# 2D Array Method Calling

Tags: java, arrays

Well firstly, I'll show my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    System.out.println("Welcome to Mine Sweeper!");
    a = promptUser(in, "What width of map would you like (3 - 20):", 3, 20);
    b = promptUser(in, "What height of map would you like (3 - 20):", 3, 20);

    char[][] map = new char[a][b];
    eraseMap(new char[a][b]);
}

public static int promptUser(Scanner in, String prompt, int min, int max) {

    int userInput;
    System.out.println(prompt);
    userInput = in.nextInt();

    while (userInput < min || userInput > max) {
        System.out.println("Expected a number from 3 to 20.");
        userInput = in.nextInt();
    }
    return userInput;
}

public static void eraseMap(char[][] map) {

    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map.length; ++j) {
            System.out.print(Config.UNSWEPT + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return;
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to create a simple minesweeper game but what this is doing is that it is not printing the game map only using the width, instead of the width + height. For example, if I input 3 as the width and 4 as the height, it would output:

```
. . .
. . .
. . .
```

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
for (int j = 0; j < map.length; ++j) {
```

to

```
for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; ++j) {
```

because `i` is the outer array `map[i]` is the inner one. Alternatively, since you don't access `map`, pass in `width` and `height` instead. Like,

```
public static void eraseMap(int width, int height) {
    for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
            System.out.print(Config.UNSWEPT + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: @BrianKang And if you swap the names of `a` and `b` then it would work... those are very poor variable names. It is `new char [height][width];` which should clarify things...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `map.length`, you can use `map[i].length` in your inner loop.